# Equality of Function Designators

Tags: function, common-lisp

Are two Common Lisp function objects with the same symbol designator always `eq`? For example, this comparison seems to work:

```
(defun foo (fn)
  (let ((ht (make-hash-table)))
    (eq (symbol-function (hash-table-test ht)) fn)))

FOO
* (foo #'eql)
T
*(foo #'equal)
NIL
```

But this may rely on implementations not making latent copies of functions, presumably for reasons of efficiency. Since `hash-table-test` returns a symbol designator, the other (possibly better) eq alternative would be to derive the symbol from the function object? Is one approach better than the other?

Comment: The return value of `hash-table-test` isn't a symbol designator, it's a function designator. If it's one of the four standard tests, it's required to be a symbol, not a symbol designator. Otherwise it can be some other type of function designator.

Comment: I don't think "symbol designator" is even a thing.

Comment: Yes, I could have been more precise, but it is a little confusing. To clarify my understanding a little more, the return value of hash-table-test is a symbol (which can be *used* as a function designator). It is the test itself that is the function designator.

Comment: When you say "derive the symbol from the funciton object", how would you do that? There's no function that returns the name of a function object.

Comment: I initially thought there might be such a function that tracked the association between a named function and its symbol, but thanks for confirming no such thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are two Common Lisp function objects with the same symbol designator always eq?

In Common Lisp a function is a piece of code, be it compiled or not. From the [Glossary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_a.htm):

> **function** *n.* 1. an *object* representing code, which can be called with zero or more arguments, and which produces zero or more values. 2. an object of type function.

A function designator, on the other hand, can be a symbol:

> **function designator** *n.* a designator for a function; that is, an object that denotes a function and that is one of: a symbol (denoting the function named by that symbol in the global environment), or a function (denoting itself).

So, a symbol which is a function designator is something that, when evaluated in a certain context, or with a certain syntax like `#'symbol` or `(function symbol)`, produces a function, and the comparison of two function designators is a comparison of the functions that they denote:

```
CL-USER> (eql #'car #'cdr)
NIL

CL-USER> (eql #'car (symbol-function 'car))
T
```

But note that this equality test is just a comparison of the identity of the functional objects (the pieces of code), like in:

```
CL-USER> (eq #'car #'car)
T
CL-USER> (let ((a (lambda (x) (1+ x))))
          (eq a a))
T
```

but not of the actual bytes that represent them (the code!):

```
CL-USER> (let ((a (lambda (x) (car x)))
          (eq a #'car))
NIL
CL-USER> (defun f (x) (1+ x))
F
CL-USER> (defun g (x) (1+ x))
G
CL-USER> (equalp (function f) (function g))
NIL
CL-USER> (equalp (lambda (x) (1+ x)) (lambda (x) (1+ x)))
NIL
```

Note that, in all these cases, the two functions compared have not only the same “meaning”, but in most cases the same “source code”, are compiled in the same way, and behaves identically on the same input data. This is because a function is mathematically a (possibly) infinite set of pairs (input, output) and one cannot compare infinte objects.

> But this may rely on implementations not making latent copies of functions, presumably for reasons of efficiency.

There is no way for the user to copy a function (neither the system has any reason to perform a copy of a piece of code!), so any function is equal to itself in the same way as any pointer is equal only to itself.

> Since hash-table-test returns a symbol designator, the other (possibly better) eq alternative would be to derive the symbol from the function object? Is one approach better than the other?

(I suppose you intend function designator, instead of symbol designator)

Actually, `hash-table-test` normally returns a function designator only as a symbol, as said in the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_hash_5.htm):

> test---a function designator. For the four standardized hash table test functions (see make-hash-table), the test value returned is always a symbol.   If an implementation permits additional tests, it is implementation-dependent whether such tests are returned as function objects or function names.

So:

```
CL-USER> (type-of (hash-table-test (make-hash-table)))
SYMBOL
CL-USER> (eq 'eql (hash-table-test (make-hash-table)))
T
CL-USER> (eq #'eql (hash-table-test (make-hash-table)))
NIL
```

Note that in the last case we are comparing a function (the value of `#'eql`) with a symbol (what is returned by `hash-table-test`) and obviously this comparison returns a false value.

In conclusion:

1. It is not very reasonable to compare functions, unless you want to know if two functions are in effect the same object in memory (for istance if the two things are the same compiled code).
2. It is always important to distinguish functions from their designations as symbols (function names) or lists, like `(LAMBDA parameters body)`, and decide what we want to actually compare.

Comment: "It is not very reasonable to compare functions."
Except if you would want to use them as a key to an alist/hash table.

Answer (score 3):

`#'eql` is equivalent to `(function eql)`. Unless there's a lexical function binding of `eql`, this is defined to return the global function definition of the symbol `eql`. That's also what `(symbol-function 'eql)` is defined to return.

So for any globally defined function `f` that isn't shadowed by a lexical definition,

```
(eq #'f (symbol-function 'f))
```

should always be true.